# Best practice for importing bulk data to AWS RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a big AWS RDS database that needs to be updated with data on a periodic basis. The data is in JSON files stored in S3 buckets.

This is my current flow:

1. Download all the JSON files locally
2. Run a ruby script to parse the JSON files to generate a CSV file matching the table in the database
3. Connect to RDS using psql
4. Use `\copy` command to append the data to the table

I would like switch this to an automated approach (maybe using an AWS Lambda). What would be the best practices?

Approach 1:
Run a script (Ruby / JS) that parses all folders in the past period (e.g., week) and within the parsing of each file, connect to the RDS db and execute an `INSERT` command. *I feel this is a very slow process with constant writes to the database and wouldn't be optimal.*

Approach 2:
I already have a Ruby script that parses local files to generate a single CSV. I can modify it to parse the S3 folders directly and create a temporary CSV file in S3. **The question is - how do I then use this temporary file to do a bulk import?**

Are there any other approaches that I have missed and might be better suited for my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: you can also run your current flow, from a lambda with psql / ruby, or if the process takes more than 15 min lambda max runtime, with an ECS task

Comment: How do I use psql \copy command to use an s3 file instead of a local one? The import process is quite quick, so time isn't an issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar  with any feature that provides that functionality.

Comment: What would be the recommendation then? My current flow is to use local files. But if I move to lambda, I would need to use a non-local file.

Comment: no you wouldn't, not unless your local file is really big.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/